# How do I add a Line break in a SQL Server Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm making a Stored Procedure that basically concatenates a long string with data from many records.

I want to do:

```
set @output = @output + 'aaa' + LINEBREAK
```

How do I specify that line break?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
DECLARE @LINEBREAK AS varchar(2)
SET @LINEBREAK = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
set @output = @output + 'aaa' + char(13)
```